# How to resize Image in Odoo 9

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

how to resize image in Odoo 9?

i make the code in models.py like this

```
image = fields.Binary("Image", default='_get_default_image',
                     help="This field holds the image used as avatar for this student, limited to 1024x1024px")
image_medium = fields.Binary(string="Medium-sized image", store=True, compute="_get_image",   inverse='_set_image',
                            help="Medium-sized image of this contact. It is automatically " \
                                 "resized as a 128x128px image, with aspect ratio preserved. " \
                                 "Use this field in form views or some kanban views.")

@api.multi
def _get_default_image(self):
    image_path = openerp.modules.get_module_resource('af', 'static/src/img', 'default_image.png')
    return tools.image_resize_image_big(open(image_path, 'rb').read().encode('base64'))

@api.multi
def _get_image(self, name, args):
    return dict((p.id, tools.image_get_resized_images(p.image)) for p in self)

@api.one
def _set_image(self, name, value, args):
    return self.write({'image': tools.image_resize_image_big(value)})
```

but, my code has an error

```
image = fields.Binary("Image", default='_get_default_image',
^
```

IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: "unexpected indent" have nothing to do with your code. You just need to adjust your indents that's all.

Comment: Sorry,
i has solved my problem. i'am delete api.multi and api.one. But my code can't read image_medium and image_small. Especially for kanban @MICROCOM